# How do you import yyyy-00-00 MySQL datetime into a PostgreSQL timestamp?

Tags: postgresql

I want to import a MySQL SQL dump into PostgreSQL 9.6. During my attempts I have fixed numerous incompatibilities:

- removing index names because collide with column names
- substituting auto_increment with serial, enums with create type, datetime with timestamp, (var)binary/blob with bytea and other minor type renames
- left-over `` ` `` quotes
- coercing 1 and null to ::boolean

The latest error is caused by values like `1947-00-00` which appear to mean "some date in 1947 with low precision". I don't know how to best continue.

```
FEHLER:  22008: Datum/Zeit-Feldwert ist außerhalb des gültigen Bereichs: »1947-00-00«
TIP:  Möglicherweise benötigen Sie eine andere »datestyle«-Einstellung.
ORT:  DateTimeParseError, datetime.c:3887
```

Note this is a different problem than 0000-00-00 datetime.

Comment: Is `1947-00-00` even a valid MySQL datetime?  I wouldn't want that in a table in the first place.  Is there any chance you could scrub these values first in MySQL before you import?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes, MySQL doesn't validate date values. You can also store 2017-02-31

Comment: you probably can import such columns as text, not dates (as they are not dates indeed). then applying some filters you can exclude (adapt) needed rows to valid dates. I suppose